# UnitOfWorkFactory class not initialized as intended

Tags: asp.net-mvc

For my learning, I created a new MVC application from scratch based on an existing (and working) solution. The problem is that my **UnitOfWorkFactory** class is not initialized and I don't know why?

Here is my class:

```
public class OrderSampleUserService : ServiceBase, IOrderSampleUserService
{
    public IEnumerable<Order> GetOrders()
    {
        using (var unitOfWork = UnitOfWorkFactory.Create())
        {
            var orderRepository = unitOfWork.Create<Order>();
            return orderRepository.GetAll().ToList();
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see, this is a pretty simple class. This class inherits of ServiceBase which is described below:

```
public class ServiceBase
{
    [Inject]
    public IUnitOfWorkFactory UnitOfWorkFactory { get; set; }
}
```

This ServiceBase class contains only the UnitOfWorkFactory which is initialized with an Inject attribute. It seems that the injection did not occur as expected.

And below is the UnitOfWorkFactory:

```
public class UnitOfWorkFactory : IUnitOfWorkFactory
{
    public IUnitOfWork Create()
    {
        var unitOfWork = new UnitOfWork();
        unitOfWork.SetupObjectContext();
        return unitOfWork;
    }
}
```

So I placed a breakpoint in the Create class above and this breakpoint is never reached. That's my problem: the UnitOfWork is never initialized. I spent several hours trying to figure out where was the problem without success.

[image]

As I said at the beginning, this code is a copy/pase of another solution who work pretty well. So I checked my code and did not found differences.

Thanks.

---

UPDATE

Here is the initialization of the IocContainer:

```
public class UnitOfWork : IUnitOfWork
{

    private ObjectContext _ObjectContext;
    private IocContainer _Container;
    public UnitOfWork()
    {
        _Container = new IocContainer();
    }
    public void SetupObjectContext()
    {            
        _ObjectContext = new ObjectContext();            
        _Container.BindToInstance<ObjectContext>(_ObjectContext);

    }

    public Repository<TRepository> Create<TRepository>() where TRepository : class
    {
        // As long as we registered created object context instance in child container
        // it will be available now to repositories during resolve            
        return new Repository<TRepository>(_ObjectContext);
    }

    public void Commit()
    {
        _ObjectContext.SaveChanges();
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        _ObjectContext.Dispose();
    }
}
```

Comment: Where is the configuration of the Ninject kernel? I think you missed to configure your `IUnitOfWorkFactory` in your IoC container.